# How to filter rows, hide/unhide columns in protected worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet for group collaboration. It is protected with a password.

Because of the password protection restriction, I am trying to compose a VBA code so other users can still filter the rows, hide/unhide the columns while in protected worksheet.

It resides in ThisWorkbook as follows:-

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    wSheet.Protect Password:="LoveisPatience", _
    UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next wSheet

With ActiveSheet
    .Protect Password:="LoveisPatience", AllowFiltering:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With

With ActiveSheet
    .Protect Password:="LoveisPatience", AllowFormattingColumns:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With

End Sub
```

With the above code, I manage to **hide** the columns which are previously complete with " Data tab> Group", but I **could not unhide** any columns.

And because of the inclusion of this "AllowFormattingColumns:", the "AllowFiltering" function for rows is now unworkable.

How can I make filter rows & hide/unhide columns work seamlessly?

Comment: I think you will find what you need here: http://codevba.com/excel/protect_worksheet.htm#.Xki07-KF6Uk. Also take a look at what Microsoft have to say on your subject. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Comment: Hi Variatus_thank you for your advice. The website you have shown above gave me good understanding of what can be done when Excel worksheet is protected. Thank you.

Comment: Each worksheet has a `Protection` object which has many properties that you can modify just as you can modify each property of a `Range` object. `ActiveSheet.Protect` creates a `Protection` object for that worksheet. No worksheet can have more than one `Protection` objects. Therefore the next `ActiveSheet.Protect` deletes the existing object and establishes another in its place. That process doesn't give the impression of efficiency. The better way would be to modify the existing. or at least remove the existing (`Unprotect`), so as not to confuse the innocent reader of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    wSheet.Protect Password:="password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
Next wSheet

With ActiveSheet
    .Protect Password:="password", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
End With
```

The problem seems to be an inconsistency between the two with statements. The second with statement (formatting columns) was blocking the first one (filtering). It was a bit strange because the rows were unlocked as it should be.

Does it work for you ?

Cheers

Comment: Hi Trib-RS25_ Thank you very much. Your code works beautifully. Thank you.